# Circular Buffer Python implementation

Tags: python, circular-buffer

I wrote the code for a circular buffer for an interviewstreet question. But as it happened, two testcases passed and the others are failing. The failure of the cause: index out f range. I tried several testcases after that to reproduce the failure. Unfortunately none of them reproduce the error. Here is the code.

> Implement a circular buffer of size N. Allow the caller to append, remove and list the contents of the buffer. Implement the buffer to achieve maximum performance for each of the operations.
>
> "A"  n -  Append the following n lines to the buffer. If the buffer is full they replace the older entries.
>   "R"  n -  Remove first n elements of the buffer. These n elements are the ones that were added earliest among the current elements.
>   "L"   - List the elements of buffer in order of their inserting time.
>   "Q"  - Quit.

```
class circbuffer():

    #initialization
    def __init__(self,size):
            self.maximum=size
            self.data=[]
            self.current=0


    #appending when the buffer is not full
    def append(self,x):
            if len(self.data)==self.maximum:
                    self.current=0
                    self.data[self.current]=x
                    self.current=(self.current+1)%self.maximum
                    self.__class__=bufferfull
            else:
                    self.data.append(x)

    def remove(self,x):
            if self.data:
                    self.data.pop(0)

    def cget(self):
            return self.data

class bufferfull:

    def append(self,x):
            if len(self.data)<self.maximum:
                    self.data.insert(self.current, x)
            else:
                    self.data[self.current]=x
            self.current=(self.current+1)%self.maximum

    def remove(self,x):
            if self.data:
                    if self.current>len(self.data):
                            self.current=0
                    self.data.pop(self.current)

    def cget(self):
            return self.data[self.current:]+self.data[:self.current]
n=input()

buf=circbuffer(n)
outputbuf=[]

while True:
    com=raw_input().split(' ')
    if com[0]=='A':
            n=int(com[1])
            cominput=[]
            for i in xrange(n):
                    cominput.append(raw_input())
            for j in cominput:
                    buf.append(j)
    elif com[0]=="R":
            n=int(com[1])
            for i in range(n):
                    buf.remove(i)
    elif com[0]=="L":
            for i in buf.cget():
                    outputbuf.append(i)
    elif com[0]=="Q":
            break

for i in outputbuf:
    print i
```

The error is pointing to `self.data.pop(self.current)` in class bufferfull. I cannot get the test data from the interviewstreet people. I am trying to come up with testcase myself to reproduce the error.

Any insights?

Comment: I think you're making it unnecessarily difficult for yourself with that `self.__class__` business.

Comment: @NPE, I will have to agree with you. I am new to Python and assigning a class to another got me pretty excited. Actually I am enamoured with Python..:) ! If there was a better way, I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: We have even less of a chance of coming up with an appropriate test case than you have being already familiar with your code...

Comment: Keep it simple. _Don't_ be clever when you can be straightforward in the same number of lines. All you need is a head pointer, a tail pointer, and a list of a fixed size. You don't need any fancy metaprogramming stuff whatsoever.

Comment: Assigning to `__class__` is silly. Design patterns (in here, you could do the same with a *strategy*) might seem like wanky overengineering but they communicate the purpose of the point of inflection and are less likely to of blow up in your face.

Comment: Last, but not least: does interviewstreet return your logging output?

Comment: @9000: I liked your comment so much that I've taken the liberty to quote it in my answer (with attribution). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I'm not sure you grok what a circular buffer is. The buffer is supposed to be a fixed size. Elements are inserted by writing into the next array location, possibly overriding any old data there; elements are removed by simply marking them as removed. At no point do you actually insert/delete elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

One bug is here:

```
def remove(self,x):
        if self.data:
                if self.current>len(self.data):
                        self.current=0
                self.data.pop(self.current)
```

If `self.current == len(self.data)`, you'll try to pop a non-existent element.

As a general remark, your implementation is way too complicated and for that reason wouldn't score very highly in my book (others might view this differently). @9000's comment to your question sums it up nicely:

> Keep it simple. Don't be clever when you can be straightforward in the same number of lines. All you need is a head pointer, a tail pointer, and a list of a fixed size. You don't need any fancy metaprogramming stuff whatsoever. – @9000

Comment: I'm flattered :) These words are so generic / common sense, to my mind, that they don't need careful attribution. I'm definitely repeating countless engineers that told the same thing before me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to stop the `index out of range` error with the code below, but the condition you are checking is wrong.

```
if self.current > len(self.data):
    self.current = 0
self.data.pop(self.current)
```

If you call `self.data.pop(len(self.data))` you will definitely get that error since lists are 0-indexed. You probably meant:

```
if self.current >= len(self.data):
    self.current = 0
self.data.pop(self.current)
```